# Usage of '--family' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead

Tags: cordova, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. I followed the official [getting started](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/). Everything is fine except when i run

```
ionic emulate ios
```

the red color console warning as below:

```
2014-11-10 10:02:23.837 ios-sim[9436:507] 
  stderrPath: /Users/apple/Projects/nodejs/ionic/tean/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-11-10 10:02:23.838 ios-sim[9436:507]
  stdoutPath: /Users/apple/Projects/nodejs/ionic/tean/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
Usage of '--family' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead.
Usage of '--retina' is deprecated in 3.x. Use --devicetypeid instead.
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7ff47ab00790 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}

Error: /Users/apple/Projects/nodejs/ionic/tean/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Even with this error the ios emulator open and run without any problem. is there any solution to get ride of this ?

ps: I also tried with:

```
ionic emulate --devicetypeid=retina
ionic emulate --devicetypeid=retina
ionic emulate --retina
```

the problem still persisted

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came across with [this thread](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issues-emulating-ios/9772/42) in the ionic forum. They give you some possible solutions:

- Run `pkill lldb` and try again.
- Reinstall `ios-sim` package.
- If you are in a **tmux session** get out of there and run the command directly from a terminal.
- Start the emulator ahead of time, because ios-sim has a timeout set if it can't connect.